# How to get the item count for an object attribute on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

My application is using Bootstrap 3 and AngularJS. I am trying to count the number of farmers markets for each state based on the filtered results on ng-repeat.

My JSON data looks something like this

```
$scope.fmData = [
{
    "MarketName": "Farm1",
    "Bakedgoods" :"N",
    "Cheese":"Y",
    "Eggs":"N",
    "latitude": 42.374858,
    "longitude": -72.519422,
    "state:": "New York"
},
{
    "MarketName": "Farm2",
    "Bakedgoods" :"N",
    "Cheese":"Y",
    "Eggs":"N"
    "latitude": 42.5728,
    "longitude": -72.1421,
    "state:": "Florida"
},
{
    "MarketName": "Farm3",
    "Bakedgoods" :"Y",
    "Cheese":"Y",
    "Eggs":"N"
    "latitude": 42.318,
    "longitude": -71.7757,
    "state:": "New York"
}
]
```

This is how I set up my ng-repeat with the custom filter:

```
<div ng-repeat="farmer in fmData | myFilter:SearchFood">
```

I am using checkboxes that would filter out and only display the farmers markets that have the selected food products.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="SearchFood.Bakedgoods" />
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
     <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="SearchFood.Cheese" />
     </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
     <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="SearchFood.Eggs" />
     </label>
</div>
```

My custom filter is like this:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
 return function(markets, range) {
  var out = [];  
  angular.forEach(markets, function(Mitem, Mindex){
    var flag = true;
    angular.forEach(range, function(Ritem, Rindex){
      if(!Ritem) return;
      MitemBoolVal = (Mitem[Rindex] == "Y");
      flag = ((MitemBoolVal == Ritem && flag)); 
    });

    if(flag){
      out.push(Mitem);
    }
  });

  return out;
}
  });
```

Here are some examples of what I am trying to achieve:

By default, if Baked Goods, Cheese, and Eggs are unchecked, I would see that New York has 2 farmer markets and Florida has 1 farmer market.

If I checked Eggs, I would see that New York has 0 farmers markets and Florida has 0 farmers markets.

If I checked Cheese, I would see that New York has 2 farmers markets and Florida has 1 farmer market.

If I checked Baked Goods and Cheese, I would see that New York has 1 farmer market and Florida has 0 farmer market.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your filter in javascript. Just inject `$filter` into your controller and then execute:

```
var filtered = $filter('myFilter')($scope.fmData, $scope.SearchFood);
```

This will give you the filtered array, and you can just loop through it:

```
$scope.statesCount = {};
filtered.forEach(function(item){
    // if item.state is not in our object yet, create it with value of 1
    if(typeof $scope.statesCount[item.state] === "undefined")
         $scope.statesCount[item.state] = 1;
    // if it is, increment its count
    else
         $scope.statesCount[item.state]++;
}
```

Then:

```
$scope.statesCount['New York'] // equals number of farmers markets in New York
$scope.statesCount['Florida'] // equals number of farmers markets in Florida
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can $index to get your `ng-repeat` count no.

```
$index = $index+1
```

or simply

`{{index+1}}` in your `ng-repeat` statement/div.

For more:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion AngularHarsh, but I am trying to count how many times an object attribute's value occurs on ng-repeat. Like, how can I count how many New York and Florida occurs in "state" on ng-repeat. If I did fmData.length, I could get the total count of farmer markets (3). However, I would like to be more specific and see that 2 farmer markets are from New York and 1 is from Florida

Comment: You should create plunker/JsFiddle for that. Will be able to help better.

Comment: kamilk was able to help me out. Thank you though! I will try learning how to use plunker/JsFiddle when I get the chance for future questions :)